# How to add custom control in MFCtoolbar

Tags: c++, mfc, cmfctoolbar

I am using `CMFCToolBar` to use the MFC Feature, and want to make a custom toolbar that is given in picture

[image]
I can add combobox but unable to add line in combobox. I have the following needs:

- Line with text in `CMFCtoolbarComboboxButtom`
- Combo box with up/down arrow for increase and decrease value.

How to add lines in `CMFCtoolbarComboBoxButton` and place multiple control such as width & height control?

Using Visual C++ 2018

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to put in some custom controls on the 'lines' using `CMFCToolbarComboboxButtom` - you need another (and im guessing custom made) control/button for that.

However, if you have unicode build, im guessing may be able to put in up/down arrows using unicode charset.